# R-studio/Oracle DB connection

Tags: database, r, oracle

I created a new DSN on my local machine. Even after doing that, I get the following error message. Can someone advice on how to fix this?

```
connection<- odbcConnect(dsn="ORADB1",uid="USERNAME",pwd="Password")
Warning messages:
    1: In odbcDriverConnect("DSN=ORADB1;UID=USERNAME;PWD=Password") :
      [RODBC] ERROR: state NA000, code 12504, message [Microsoft][ODBC driver for Oracle][Oracle]ORA-12504: TNS:listener was not given the SERVICE_NAME in CONNECT_DATA
    2: In odbcDriverConnect("DSN=ORADB1;UID=USERNAME;PWD="Password") :
       [RODBC] ERROR: state 01000, code 0, message [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The driver doesn't support the version of ODBC behavior that the application requested (see SQLSetEnvAttr).
    3: In odbcDriverConnect("DSN=ORADB1;UID=USERNAME;PWD=Password") :
       ODBC connection failed
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure if this works with basic R command line first.

Based on the error msg, system(or r studio) does not recognize the new DSN and driver. Did you put it into user DSN or system DSN?